# Replacing Wooden 4x8 siding

Tags: siding, replacement

a family member has just purchased  a 1970s home (California shed style) with 4x8 wood siding. The siding has deteriorated over the years due to neglect and many surrounding trees which made a damp environment. There is significant rot and carpenter bee and woodpecker damage.

My questions: Should the siding be removed before replacing it? What would be a good replacement siding?
[image]

Comment: `Should the siding be removed before replacing it`  .... you cannot "replace" something without removing it first ..... do you mean to ask if it is ok to cover the old siding? ..... just think about what could happen over time if you nail a good piece of wood to a rotten piece of wood

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean, nailing the new over the old.  That is what one contractor has suggested doing. It seems to me that a test sheet should be removed to see what is behind it ie. plywood, insulation, etc. thanks!

Comment: did you read the whole comment?

Comment: yes, I did. You say remove it all.I'm just saying a first step could be, see what you're dealing with underneath and plan accordingly.

Comment: i did not say "remove it all" ... your question was actually unclear .... you asked `Should the siding be removed before replacing it?` .... there is no mention of checking the fitness of the existing siding .... I simply pointed out the possibility of having new siding come in permanent contact with rotten wood

Comment: I apologize for my lack of communication skills. I'm trying to understand what you believe is the right thing to do with this siding. Are you suggesting that cutting out the rotten parts, patching them, and then applying the new siding over the whole exterior is an acceptable way, even if it is not the preferable way?

Comment: i am asking you to use your brain and think about what happens when you place good wood in contact with rotten wood, and leave it that way for a long period of time

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the t1-11 siding and replace with hardi-plank along with new facia and soffits...